# Registry entry gets removed after upgrading C# windows application

Tags: winforms, .net-4.0, registrykey

I have created my windows application using .net 3.5 framework and now updated to .net 4.0. After upgrading to 4.0 my application is removing registry entries.

What I need to do to resolve this issue?

Comment: please give more information. what registry entries and when are they removed? is your application supposed to change registry values?

Comment: New version removes registry entry of my own application. and Yes, every time new version installed, my application supposed to updated version number in registry value but unfortunately it is removing entry/subkey.

Comment: i have to say i tried and had no problem writing registry with .net 4.0...
can you share your code and show where is the problem?

Comment: I have added one more method at COMMIT action of installation to add registry and now it works well... anyway thanks Liran Elisha for replying and doing workaround. But this is not the solution, its a kind of patch.